Google Cloud SUSE Linux VM ignoring startup script to regain root access
I tried to increase the size of my VM's sda disk but it is now stuck in boot loop as the root sda partition did not resize.
Unfortunately, the VM has a root password that has not been documented so I can't use any sudo commands in the serial console. So I want to temporarily set a new root password via this startup script:
#! /bin/bash
echo root:<imagine temp pw here> | chpasswd

After a reboot, I try to switch to root via sudo su - and enter my new password, but the password fails.
The VM runs SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15 SP1.

Please refer to this similar lowendtalks community issue, which may help you to resolve the issue.

thank you, but my case is a tad different, I am using the text panel "startup script" in the GCE settings, so no dedicated file
